# Remove different number of NaN at the end of every columns from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

It always has extra blanks at the end of each column in CSV file from users. Like this CSV:

```
847,73.3,809,74.9,655,80.6,694,45.5,647,47.8
848,24.3,810,23.1,656,18.2,695,48.6,648,47.3
566,26.1,541,7.8,438,19.1,463,45.5,433,18.2
567,0.5,542,0.1,439,0.2,464,53.1,434,0.2
426,0.0,407,0.0,330,0.0,348,98.6,326,0.0
...
339,37.9,324,74.9,,,349,1.4,,
340,62.0,325,25.1,,,,,,
341,0.1,326,0.0,,,,,,
```

Which turn into NaN after using pandas

```
pd.read_csv(ref_file)
```

Result

```
0                      694.0        45.5                     647.0        47.8  
1                      695.0        48.6                     648.0        47.3  
2                      696.0         5.6                     649.0         4.8  
3                      697.0         0.3                     650.0         0.2  
4                      698.0         0.0                     432.0        81.6  
5                      463.0        45.5                     433.0        18.2  
6                      464.0        53.1                     434.0         0.2  
7                      465.0         1.4                     324.0        81.6  
8                      466.0         0.0                     325.0        18.4  
9                      348.0        98.6                     326.0         0.0  
10                     349.0         1.4                       NaN         NaN  
11                       NaN         NaN                       NaN         NaN  
12                       NaN         NaN                       NaN         NaN
```

I tried

```
df.last_valid_index()
```

but it checks only first column. All of this column has different number of NaN at the end, how to remove NaN in this case?

Edit: I tried .dropna(). It doesn't work as it cut all row according to the max number of NaN column. I want to cut NaN just the number each column has and it should have different number of row at the end.

Comment: Have you tried [`df.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)?

Comment: @Craig Thanks for advice. I just tried it but it removed all row of NaN. Now every columns are cut to 9 which is not my purpose. I want remove NaN just what they have in each column.

Comment: Pandas doesn't work that way. All columns have the same length in a dataframe and any missing values are indicated by NaNs as placeholders. Missing values are properly handled by the operations in Pandas. What is the problem you are trying to solve by removing the NaNs?

Comment: Is this the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each column as a list and those lists as a series

```
df.T.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)

0    [847.0, 848.0, 566.0, 567.0, 426.0, 339.0, 340...
1        [73.3, 24.3, 26.1, 0.5, 0.0, 37.9, 62.0, 0.1]
2    [809.0, 810.0, 541.0, 542.0, 407.0, 324.0, 325...
3         [74.9, 23.1, 7.8, 0.1, 0.0, 74.9, 25.1, 0.0]
4                  [655.0, 656.0, 438.0, 439.0, 330.0]
5                         [80.6, 18.2, 19.1, 0.2, 0.0]
6           [694.0, 695.0, 463.0, 464.0, 348.0, 349.0]
7                  [45.5, 48.6, 45.5, 53.1, 98.6, 1.4]
8                  [647.0, 648.0, 433.0, 434.0, 326.0]
9                         [47.8, 47.3, 18.2, 0.2, 0.0]
dtype: object
```

Otherwise, if you want each row as a list.

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)

0    [847.0, 73.3, 809.0, 74.9, 655.0, 80.6, 694.0,...
1    [848.0, 24.3, 810.0, 23.1, 656.0, 18.2, 695.0,...
2    [566.0, 26.1, 541.0, 7.8, 438.0, 19.1, 463.0, ...
3    [567.0, 0.5, 542.0, 0.1, 439.0, 0.2, 464.0, 53...
4    [426.0, 0.0, 407.0, 0.0, 330.0, 0.0, 348.0, 98...
5               [339.0, 37.9, 324.0, 74.9, 349.0, 1.4]
6                           [340.0, 62.0, 325.0, 25.1]
7                             [341.0, 0.1, 326.0, 0.0]
dtype: object
```